# Obfsproxy error on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: obfsproxy

I have Ubuntu 17.04 and have installed Obfsproxy:
sudo apt install obfsproxy

Installation was successfull, so I run it:

sudo obfsproxy -v

Unfortunately, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/obfsproxy", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py",
line 3019, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py",
line 3003, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py",
line 3032, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py",
line 646, in _build_master
    ws = cls()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py",
line 639, in __init__
    self.add_entry(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py",
line 695, in add_entry
    for dist in find_distributions(entry, True):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py",
line 2012, in find_on_path
    if len(os.listdir(fullpath)) == 0:
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zope.interface-4.4.2.dist-info'
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: You should just use obfs4proxy instead of the older obfsproxy

Comment: Obfsproxy is well-known "has to be built from sources by hand", I was ending up with a build script rather than even using pip - only after that no glitches were so far.

Answer (score 1):

OK, found the problem... I have installed some packages through pip before and it seems there are some conflicts in Ubuntu... So you need to install Obfsproxy to virtual environment:

```
sudo pip install virtualenv
virtualenv venv
source ~/venv/bin/activate
pip install obfsproxy

~/venv/bin/obfsproxy -v
```